# Java method call return

Tags: java, methods, call

Guys.
I'm trying to capture or 'trap' the return value that is returned from a java method call.

For example: 
Class A has a method that returns an int value. Class B calls that particular method (from class A) and wants to trap the result from the method call.

How do I do this exactly?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: This surely can be best answered by going through any introductory Java tutorial, no?

Comment: u mean this?
<br>
1/
define the method from the class A static then assign the method call to an integer variable for example
`
    class B{
          ///////code
          A.a()
          ///////code
    }
`
2/
define the method from the class A void then assign the method call to an integer variable for example
`
    class B{
          ///////code
          A obj=new A();
          obj.a();
          ///////code
    }`

Comment: @NathanFox Did you find the answers helpful? If so, please accept one by clicking the checkmark next to it. Otherwise, let us know what help you still need.

Comment: @DizzyCode - Before trying to claim rep, I would suggest that you work on getting your examples right.

Comment: @HotLicks I am only informing OP of this function as he is likely new to SO.  In any case, can you show me what is still incorrect about my answer? I would appreciate feedback.

Answer (score 3):

```
class A {
  public int someMethod() {
    return 1;
  }
}

class B {
  public void testMethod() {
    A a = new A();
    int value = a.someMethod();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting a variable equal to the int value returned by the method. Say you have `methodA()` in `ClassA`:

```
public int methodA() {
    return 0;
}
```

In `ClassB`, you would first need to create an instance of `ClassA`. When you call the method, set another variable, in this case `returnedValue()`, equal to it. This allows you to reuse the value without calling the method again.

```
ClassA objectOfA = new ClassA(); //instantiation
int returnedValue = objectOfA.methodA(); //returnedValue = 0
```

Comment: How can you call methodA() with the class name without making it static ?

Comment: Thank you for the edit! I also improved the explanation.

Comment: If the method is static, why do you need an instance of ClassA? You only need an instance of ClassA if the method is not static.